# jQuery - select childrens separately for each parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

Take look at this example http://jsfiddle.net/hKASH/

```
    <div id="a">
    <div class="parent">
        <span>one</span>
        <span>two</span>
        <span>three</span>
    </div>
    <div class="parent">
        <span>one</span>
        <span>two</span>
    </div>
</div>

$('#a .parent').children().slice(1).css('float', 'right');
```

I want to select children groups separately for each parent, "one" must stay left, others must go to right.

Now it looks like I have children() with 5 elements, I want to have 2 groups with 3 and 2 elements.

Thanks

Comment: Silly me, I thought I tried with each(), but it didn't work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) function to loop through each parent

try this

```
 $('#a .parent').each(function(){
   $(this).children().slice(1).css('float', 'right');
 });
```

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/7SvDC/)

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to do it in two steps:

```
$('#a .parent').each ( function () {
  $(this).children().slice(1).css('float', 'right');
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to do it for **each** of your parent elements.

```
$('#a .parent').each(function (i, item) {
    $(this).children().slice(1).css('float', 'right');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var children;
$.each('.parent',function(i,v){children[i] = $(v).children('span')})
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it seems to work:

```
$('.parent').each(function(){
    $(this).find('span:first').css('float', 'right');
});
```

But yes you will need each..